# Need clarification on this return type

Tags: objective-c

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462937/objective-c-cocoahttpserver-trying-to-do-a-simple-get-request-with-one-paramet) post here and I am not sure on the validity of the code. 
However I never came across something like this or read anything about this (I just started objectiveC). Here is the code sample

```
@implementation MyHTTPConnection

    - (NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path
    {
    HTTPLogTrace();

    if ([path isEqualToString:@"/getElement"])
    {
            NSData *data = ...
            HTTPDataResponse *response = [[HTTPDataResponse alloc] initWithData:data];
            return response;
    }

        // default behavior for all other paths  
    return [super httpResponseForMethod:method URI:path];
    }

@end
```

My question is what is the return type here ?

```
(NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)
```

It looks to me as a NSObject pointer that implements the HTTPResponse Object.
I am of the opinion that it could be simply written like this

```
NSObject *
```

Am I missing anything ? I am not sure why the above would be chosen. Especially with the NSObject . Any suggestions , clarifications on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `NSObject` that implements the `HTTPResponse` protocol. So you can call any `HTTPResponse` methods on the returned value.

If `HTTPResponse` inherits from the `NSObject` protocol (which is distinct from the `NSObject` class), then the usual way to express this is `id<HTTPResponse>`. But `NSObject<HTTPResponse> *` isn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It means

> NSObject pointer that implements the HTTPResponse protocol

So you were close. It could be `NSObject *`, but you'd be loosing a lot of information that the compiler can use and you'd need to do a lot of casting to compensate for that.

In a number of ways it would be better to use `id < HTTPResponse >` and to ensure that the `HTTPResponse` protocol extended the `NSObject` protocol as this provides the required guarantees to the compiler but also gives more flexibility in the underlying object type (for instance to use an `NSProxy`).